# What happens with a 401k when changing citizenship?

Tags: united-states, 401k, citizenship

I am in the process of changing citizenship from the U.S. to Norway. When I told my financial advisor about this he said I would have to close my 401k account there but he didn't really offer any advice on what to do with it. Is this correct that a citizenship change will require a 401k to be closed or is that something perhaps particular to the rules of that financial institution? It seems very difficult to find any practical information on this.

Comment: That seems very odd.  My citizenship was not US when I opened my 401k account. Are you also changing employers? It may be that the conditions of the 401k require you to roll the 401k into an IRA or other retirement account if you move from the employer supplying the 401k.

Comment: I have worked for a Norwegian employer for 9 years, so the 401k was bascially from all my previous U.S. employers combined into one account. Maybe they just don't want to deal with the IRS rules or something regarding reporting about it. I'm not sure. This is a U.S. branch of RBC (Royal Bank of Canda) so it's not like a small institution or anything like that. I'm also not implying anything bad about them, it's just what the advisor told me in a meeting.

Comment: But maybe that explains why I can't find any information about this rule, if there is actually no rule about it...

Comment: Yes, they probably don't want to comply with [FBAR / FACTA reporting](https://www.irs.gov/uac/newsroom/taxpayers-with-foreign-assets-may-have-fbar-and-fatca-filing-requirements-in-june)  requirements for people holding US-based accounts and non-US-based accounts.

Comment: why change? can't you keep both citizenships?

Comment: I'm curious why you are choosing to change citizenship? I am also looking into Norwegian citizenship, but found that you don't have to renounce your US citizenship due to the "undue financial hardship" of paying the fees associated with renouncing American citizenship. So you could essentially keep both passports and be a dual citizen?

Comment: @njzk2 I don't think Norway allow dual citizenship - people born with two, must choose one of them when they turn 18 (or so).  There are some talk in Norway to change this though...  Of course an alternative to citizenship is to just get "permanent resident status" - many settling in Norway choose this option.

Comment: I would say keep it and then report it to Norwegian authorities.  You could perhaps enquire to somehow get it transferred to a Norwegian bank or insurer that offer pension-insurance.  Working in Norway automatically (except if you're self-employed) enrolls you in Folketrygden - which includes pension and health-benefits/insurance.  Your pension is determent by a percentage of what you've earned while working in Norway until you retire.  Some opts to buy *additional* health-insurance and/or pension - to pay for care at private hospitals, and get more pension than the Government offer. TBC

Comment: The money you pay to Folketrygden, is made by your employer from your salaries - along with taxes.  Many private employers use services at banks to provide (additional) pension-insurance for their employers.  These are transferable (so-called "fripolise"); so even if your first employer used bank A and your second employer used insurance-company B, you can transfer all your saved-up pension from these to bank C... if you find that bank C gives you a better offer and manages you money better.  **Perhaps your 401k can somehow be transferred into such a "fripolise"?**

Answer (score 13):

There is no relation between changing citizenship and 401k, and no need to act on it because of a change in citizenship.

Depending on you specific situation and the size of the 401k, there might be some tax consequences anyway; but *closing* it is for sure not required.

Comment: Given that the OP says that his financial advisor say otherwise, a link supporting your assertion is needed.

Comment: It is hard to link to something that doesn't exist. Try https://www.greenbacktaxservices.com/blog/renouncing-and-your-401k/, which explains some consequences, but does (obviously) not mention that 401 k must be closed. Same here: https://www.taxesforexpats.com/articles/expatriation/what_happens_toyour_401(k)_after_you_give_upus_citizenship.html. Actually, you cannot simply close a 401k, as there are severe tax consequences

Comment: @DJClayworth I fail to see why.  Financial advisors say silly things all the time. Especially the *many* who actually are paid commission to put you into financial instruments. They want their $5k commission and will happily cost you $100k in tax penalties to get it.  For instance my 401k provider *regularly* solicits me to close out my 401k and convert it to IRA, very silly thing to do, the former is protected from bankruptcy and the latter is not.

Comment: @Harper Financial advisors say silly things.. But random people on the internet also say silly things, and probably much more frequently.

Answer (score 8):

My guess is that it's not a rule, it's just that the 401k manager doesn't want to deal with [FBAR / FACTA reporting requirements](https://www.irs.gov/uac/newsroom/taxpayers-with-foreign-assets-may-have-fbar-and-fatca-filing-requirements-in-june) for those with foreign assets.

Comment: This might be it. I used to have a tiny Swiss bank account (Swiss relatives used it for my Christmas money) and in the early 2000s they got rid of all small US clients.

Comment: What the 401k manager wants you to do and what you're obliged to do are two different things.  When I left a job, Fidelity came at me *like I needed to convert my 401K to IRA.  When I asked, they admitted I could leave it right there.  Turns out their interest was to recommend me into their IRA products which are more profitable for them.

Answer (score 3):

The one item to be aware of is if you are considered a covered individual and are therefore subject to an exit tax. If you are then you while you can keep tax deferred accounts open, you must pay tax on the value of the account as if it was a full distribution (but at least no penalty). Also non-qualified investments will be considered to have been sold on the day prior to renouncing your citizenship.

The thresholds for the exit tax appear to be $2 million in assets (including property) or somewhere around $150k in salary.

Good google search terms for finding information are "us exit tax" and "renouncing us citizenship tax deferred account".

I would recommend working with an international tax expert who does exit taxes if you might be hit by this tax.